# Margin won't scroll away in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

On Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, the CSS below adds a 100 pixel margin to the top of the page, and the margin disappears if you scroll down.  This is what I want.

In Internet Explorer 8, the margin continues to be at the top of the browser no matter how far you scroll down.  How can I make it behave the way it does in the other browsers?

```
body {
   border-top: 100px solid #DE2A00;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   }
```

Comment: No, the CSS you posted adds a 100px border to the top of the body and no margin at all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have `border-top:100px solid #DE2A00;` on body tag that will not create margin and secondly you are giving `margin:0;` so margin will work, so its totally wrong css acc to your requirement.

If you want margin from top in body tag then see below css

```
body
{
margin: 100px 0 0; /* or margin-top:100px; or  margin: 100px 0 0 0 ;*/
padding: 0;
}
```